# Delete list item ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html-lists, reactjs

I have managed to create a list using ReactJS where you type something in and it adds it to the list underneath the text box. However, I now want the user to be able to delete something from that list.

Here is some code:

```
var ToDoList = React.createClass({

  deleteItem: function(item){
    var items = this.state.items.filter(function(itm) {
      return item.id !== itm.id;
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    var DeleteClick=this.deleteItem;        
    var listItems = this.props.listItems.map(function(submittedValue) {
      return (
          <ToDoListItem key={submittedValue.id}>{submittedValue.text}<button onClick={DeleteClick}> X </button></ToDoListItem>

      )
    });
    return (
        <ul className="toDoList">
          {listItems}

        </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

This code generates this error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteItem' of undefined`

Here is some more code as to how I am generating the adding to the list:

```
var i = 1;
var ToDoForm = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {text: '', submittedValues: [{id: '000001', text: 'Rich'}, {id: '000002', text: 'Simon'}]};
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({text: event.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var submittedValue = {text: this.state.text, id: i++};
    this.setState({submittedValues: this.state.submittedValues.concat(submittedValue)});
    this.setState({text: ''});
    console.log("ToDo: " + this.state.submittedValues);
  },

  render: function() {

    return (
        <div>
          <h1> todos </h1>

          <form className="todoForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Type out a task"
                value={this.state.text}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            <input
                type="submit"
                value="Submit todo"
                />
          </form>

          <h2> Data should appear here </h2>

          <ToDoList listItems={this.state.submittedValues}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Not sure how to get the delete to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set `this` to `.map` because `this` refers to global scope not to `ToDoList` object,

```
var listItems = this.props.listItems.map(function(submittedValue) {
   // your code
}, this);
```

Comment: what needs to go inside the deleteItem function though?

Comment: @The Hurricane could you clarify what do you mean

Comment: sure. I have edited the code above to reflect what my code looks like including your changes. currently when I click on my button nothing happens when what I want is for it to delete that particular item. something must be wrong in my deleteItem function but I cannot work it out. can you see any errors?

Comment: @The Hurricane I've created example based on your code - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/22297/.

Comment: couple of questions. 1) line 31 why no closing tag for ToDoListItem? 2) line 18 what does el stand for? 3) mine is looking like this: `Rich onDelete=`

Comment: @The Hurricane 1. you can use short syntax /> instead of </ToDoListItem>;

Comment: @The Hurricane 2. you can use any name like item or what you want, I prefer el

Answer (score 1):

you have to try the below mentioned code as:

```
var DeleteClick=this.deleteItem;
var listItems = this.props.listItems.map(function(submittedValue) {
  return (
      <ToDoListItem key={submittedValue.id}>{submittedValue.text}<button onClick={DeleteClick}> X </button></ToDoListItem>

  )
});
```

you have used `this` keyword in map function and scope of this is limited to map function only that's y it's causing the prob

Comment: `cannot read properties items of null` is the error presumably because the items variable has nothing in it

Comment: @TheHurricane: yes because you haven't set state in your ToDoList Component

Comment: what should be in that delete function then?

Comment: you should use this.props.listItems insted of this.state.items

Comment: actually whatever you have done in your child component do it in parent and apply the filter on state data once state changed it would automatically call the render method and your view updated

Answer (score 0):

The context of `this` inside the `map` function does not reference the enclosing React class. In order to reference the React class using `this` inside the map function, pass `this` to the map function:

```
var listItems = this.props.listItems.map(fn, this)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [ES6](http://es6-features.org/) - you can use [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for lexical binding.
Also, the best way to handle adding/updating/deleting items in your list is to use [Immutability helpers](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) provided by [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html)

```
var listItems = this.props.listItems.map( submittedValue => {
      <ToDoListItem key={submittedValue.id}>{submittedValue.text}<button onClick={this.deleteItem}> X </button></ToDoListItem>
});
```